# hot to make the IF statement to recognize an image inside a div and change it with onclick function?

Tags: javascript, image

i have a problem , i am trying to build a website (and my JS skills are not to good still ) i have an onclick function which will make JS to display an image inside a div ("gallerym")

i was trying for days now to work on a new oncklick function up()
basically its an up arrow and using the IF statement it should recognize the image inside "gallerym"  and show a different image inside "gallerym" .

the best i could was a code that created another "gallerm" and displaying both images.

please help me to find the right code .

many thanks in advance!

```
       function up() {
   var gallerym = document.getElementById('gallerym');
   var myImage = gallerym.querySelector('img');
   var imageArray = ['../images/gallery/10cmto100cmm600x600.jpg', 
'../images/gallery/10cmto100cmt600x600.jpg',
```

'../images/gallery/1mto10mm600x600.jpg','../images/gallery/1mto10mm600x600.jpg']
        var currentIndex = imageArray.findIndex(myImage.src)
       // Change the src to the next image, but first checking if the src is the 
      last item, so you resest to first item instead
       var lastItem = imageArray[imageArray.length - 1]
       myImage.src = imageArray[currentIndex] == lastItem ? imageArray[0] : 
       imageArray[currentIndex + 1]
        // No need for the if statement again
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you so much for trying to help !! i was able to figure this out :

this is what i did:  works like a charm

```
function up () {               
 if
(document.getElementById("gallerymain")
.getAttribute('src') 
 == "../images/gallery/image1.jpg") 
   {
    document.getElementById("gallerymain").src = 
 "../images/gallery/image2.jpg"
    }
  else if   
 (document.getElementById("gallerymain")
 .getAttribute('src') 
  == "../images/gallery/image3.jpg") 
    {
    document.getElementById("gallerymain").src = 
 "../images/gallery/image4.jpg"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I guess the function up is the function you passed to the eventListener.

```
   function up() {
    var gallerym = document.getElementById('gallerym');
    var myImage = gallerym.querySelector('img');
    var imageArray = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 
                       'image4.jpg']
    var currentIndex = imageArray.findIndex(myImage.src)
    // Change the src to the next image, but first checking if the src is the last item, so you resest to first item instead
    var lastItem = imageArray[imageArray.length - 1]
    myImage.src = imageArray[currentIndex] == lastItem ? imageArray[0] : imageArray[currentIndex + 1]
    // No need for the if statement again
  }
```

Comment: hello @Ikechukwu Eze , thank you so much for responding , i just didnt figured out the "my-image " thing . i didnt gave an id to this image . when the div is displayed in default mode there is no image inside . so i dont really understand what to do with this "my-image" id

Comment: thank you thank you thank you so much!!! i been breaking my head over it !! god bless you my friend

Comment: can i also ask you please how to make it work with image 3 and image 4 ?

Comment: @VANGOOSE I just edited to fit this request. check it out

Comment: thank you again , what did you ment in "change the src to the next image ?

Comment: and what did you ment by "NO need for IF again" i dont need the IF at all or just once ?

Comment: Not at all,  except you want to convert the ternary statement to if statement. @VANGOOSE it should work now without glitches. I just edited it

Comment: since i am new to JS i didnt understood the :// Change the src to the next image, but first checking if the src is the last item, so you resest to first item instead  , do i need to change something or judt copy paste your code . what i did was to copy and paste your code and changed the images in the array to the directories of my images , what am i doing wrong ?  i edited my code so you can see what i did

Comment: It is cos the image links in your array are relative paths, try using full path. Like... 'http://example.com/images/someimage.jpg'

Comment: but i didnt uploaded my website yet so the images are from folders .

Comment: check the link of the first image when it is rendered on the webpage and make others look like that in the array

Comment: If what you want to make is a carousel, this is a link to a carousel I made on codepen https://codepen.io/IkezeKings/pen/ErKRKb

Comment: @ Ikechukwu Eze  thank you so much for all your help !! i learned alot  !!! i was able to figure it out .  check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the last if/else to the first one and just make an else if statement.

```
var gallerym = document.getElementById('gallerym');
var myImage = gallerym.querySelector('img');

if (myImage.src == 'image1.jpg') {
    myImage.src = 'image2.jpg'
}else   if (myImage.src == 'image3.jpg') {
    myImage.src = 'image4.jpg'
} else if (myImage.src == 'image3.jpg') {
    myImage.src = 'image3.jpg'
}
 else {
    myImage.src = 'image1.jpg'
}
```

or Switch Statement

```
switch(myImage.src) {
  case 'image1.jpg':
    myImage.src = 'image2.jpg'
    break;
  case 'image3.jpg':
    myImage.src = 'image4.jpg'
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

Comment: in this case it will show image 4 after image 1 and after image 3. i need image 4 to be shown after image 3 only .  and image 2 after image one only

Comment: in the first sugestion everything will change to image 1 eventually , the second code is not working at all , thank you

Comment: i noticed that the == isnt working , else if (myImage.src == '../images/gallery/1mto10mm600x600.jpg')  this is how i specify the directory to the image and its right . why is my == wont work?